# Set-ADUser -Manager entity with Contact

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a csv with the following fields:

User             | AD_Manager_ID | Dyn_Manager_ID
abc@mydomain.com |  1234         | 1455

The Dyn_Manager_ID field is the employeeID of another user.
99% of the time it corresponds to an actual user, but sometimes it corresponds to a **contact**

I can get the contact like this:

```
Get-ADObject -Filter "employeeID -eq '1455'"
```

but when I try to Set-ADUser -Manager with that object, it returns a 'Cannot find an object with idenity" error.

Here is the code for regular users (non contacts):

```
$csvimport = import-csv -Path C:\Users\ME\Desktop\AccountChangesCSV.csv
foreach ($User in $csvimport)
{
  Get-aduser -filter "employeeID -eq '$($user.DYN_Mgr_ID)'" | select-object samaccountname - 
OutVariable ManagersName

Get-ADUser -Filter "employeeID -eq '$($user.AD_ID)'" | set-aduser -Manager 
$ManagersName.samaccountname
}
```

Comment: Use the `DistinguishedName` from the `Get-ADObject -Filter "employeeID -eq '1455'"` object. Then, this seems wrong: `Get-ADUser -Filter "employeeID -eq '$($user.AD_Email)'"`. I do not know your input CSV, but shouldn't that be `Get-ADUser -Filter "employeeID -eq '$($user.EmployeeID)'"` ?

Comment: Hey Theo, thanks for this. Sorry for the confusion, I have edited the code above. 
But Get-ADObject IS using distinguished name
So for ex:
    $varManager = Get-ADObject -Filter "employeeID -eq '19777'" | Select DistinguishedName
    Get-ADUser -Filter "employeeID -eq '1234'" | Set-ADUser -Manager $varManager
This gives the "Cannot find an object with identity CN=Your User, OU= Your OU" etc. etc. error message

Answer (score 1):

If someone's manager could be either another user or a contact, then do not use `Get-ADUser` to find the manager object, but `Get-ADObject` instead.

If this was a contact, there is no `SamAccountName` property, but instead, you can use the `DistinguishedName` or the `ObjectGUID`

Try

```
$csvimport = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\ME\Desktop\AccountChangesCSV.csv'
foreach ($user in $csvimport) {
    $manager = Get-ADObject -Filter "employeeID -eq '$($user.DYN_Mgr_ID)'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($manager) {
        # now update the users Manager property with the DistinguishedName of the manager object
        Get-ADUser -Filter "employeeID -eq '$($user.AD_ID)'" | 
        Set-ADUser -Manager $manager.DistinguishedName  # or ObjectGUID instead of DistinguishedName
    }
}
```

This works for both AD user objects and contacts alike

Comment: So this is basically what I tried, but it still returns the cannot find an object. It might be because the CN/Distinguished name contains a special character.  Like this:

CN=Thomas O'neil,OU=Accounts...

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I wouldn't do `objectSID` because I don't think `Get-ADObject` returns that property, but I may be wrong there.. `ObjectGUID` should work though

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Oh, well.. do `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` out of habit there I guess (always did and never hurt me). It kind of grew on me..

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon BTW, I have added your tip about `ObjectGUID` in the answer. Thanks for that!

Comment: No, still the same issue when $manager.ObjectGUID used.
It returns "Cannot find object" error

Answer (score 1):

I think this post has the answer: [updating an ADUser's Manager with a contact card](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5c819007-cee7-4bad-a4a4-514dfed5231c/updating-an-adusers-manager-with-a-contact-card?forum=winserverpowershell)

This is the code that finally worked for me:

```
$csvimport = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\ME\Desktop\AccountChangesCSV.csv'
foreach ($user in $csvimport) {
$manager = Get-ADObject -Filter "employeeID -eq '$($user.DYN_Mgr_ID)'" - 
ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($manager) {
    # now update the users Manager property with the DistinguishedName of the 
manager object
    $aduser = Get-ADUser -Filter "employeeID -eq '$($user.AD_ID)'"
    Set-AdUser -Identity $aduser.SamAccountName  -replace 
@{manager="$($manager.distinguishedname)"}
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm wondering, on Theo's answer you commented that the error was `Cannot find an object with Identity: 'CN=Thomas O'neil....` was `CN=Thomas O'neil` the User or the Manager?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon It was the manager. 
Get-ADObject had no trouble getting the manager, however Set-ADUser -Manager was not able to set. So I could GET the contact, but not SET the contact.